# How can I disable spell checking for a block of text in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, spell-check

When I am editing a plain text document and making notes in it, TextMate will put red lines under parts of it which should not be spell checked:

[image]

How can I disable spell checking for a block of text? I don't even mind if I have to wrap it inside of something like `{{` and `}}`.

In the [Textmate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text) it says

> Since TextMate is intended for structured text it is possible to exclude parts of the document from being checked. This is done by creating a preferences item in the bundle editor, setting spellChecking to 0 and filling in the scope selector with the selector to target for no spell checking.

But I am still unclear about how to do this - I don't even see the spelling section in my preference pane (`cmd+,`, right?)

I'm looking for a few step-by-step instructions of how to disable spell checking for part of a plain text document.

Comment: What textmate version?

Comment: @DanielBeck 1.5.10 (latest)

Comment: What programming language / syntax is this?

Comment: It's a plain text file that I use for reference. I don't like that it is underlining mis-spellings for code words. i suggested delimiters for "scoped" sections of `{{` and `}}` but i would be open to other delimiters. i do want it to check spelling on the actual text part of the document.

Comment: No, I meant what language for syntax highlighting etc. do you have selected in TextMate? *Plain text* then?

Comment: yes that's correct. also tried markdown but i think plaintext may be better as i'm not really using structured markup in a lot of my existing .txt files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMate uses user-configurable bundles of scripts and language definitions for syntax highlighting, indentation recognition, and the menu items in the *Bundles* menu.

TextMate can be extended by adding new bundles to e.g. support other programming languages.

Likewise, you can edit existing bundles to match your custom requirements.

---

You can view your bundles and their contents via *Bundles » Bundle Editor » Show Bundle Editor*.

The following instructions will explain how to ignore the text between two delimiters for spell checking.

[image]

1. Open the Bundle Editor
2. Select the *Text* bundle's *Plain text* language entry in the list.
3. Add the following to the list of `patterns` matched under `contentName = 'meta.paragraph.text'` as a sibling to the block whose name is `markup.underline.link.text`:

   ```
   {   name = 'meta.no-spellcheck';
       begin = '{{';
       end = '}}';
   },
   ```

   This defines a new scope, named `meta.no-spellcheck`, as a subscope to the regular `meta.paragraph.text` scope. So only if a scope is a regular text paragraph will it also possibly be a `meta.no-spellcheck` scope, and therefore excluded from spell checking.
4. In the *Text » Spell Checking: Disable* item, add `meta.no-spellcheck` to the *Scope Selector* list. This will apply the rule to all `meta.no-spellcheck` scopes.
5. Close the Bundle Editor and test your changes (no saving needed).

---

To view a certain position's active scopes, press `Ctrl-Shift-P`. This can help you in defining your own rules.

[image]

Comment: any chance to update this for TM 2?

Comment: @tim It's basically the same. I haven't used TextMate in years and got it to work with my instructions above. A handful of labels (e.g. *Text* bundle instead of *Plain text*) and menu items (e.g. *Bundles » Edit Bundles* instead of *Bundles » Bundle Editor » Show Bundle Editor*) are different and that's about it. How to define the scope is a bit different, but as there are pre-existing scopes one can just copy and paste from the others.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck! I've added this Q & A  now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565216/how-do-i-get-textmate-2-to-enable-spellchecking-in-a-scope-that-is-not-checked-b/41565217#41565217